# Adding Bing Translation on windows phone 7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to use Bing translation Service on windows phone 7.1, is there a specific way of doing it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lmaaa95 -- You don't need any DLLs to use Microsoft Translator on Windows Phone.

Microsoft provide APIs that can be called with HTTP or SOAP.

I've blogged on how to do it here:
http://www.netnavi.tv/2012/05/29/using-microsoft-translator-with-windows-phone-7/

There's also an article here on building WP7.x apps with it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872395.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yep, there are APIs that you can tap into :)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/developers.aspx

Comment: Yp But im having problems in adding them to windows phone 7.1 since some of the dll are not supported

Comment: @Imaa95 - What problems exactly?  I know Windows Phone 7 supports what you need to use.